# Could not find gem in Nexus

Tags: ruby, rubygems, version, bundler, nexus

I'm currently trying to bundle install a gem from Nexus. I can access earlier versions but get the message 'Could not find gem '' in rubygems repository . Seem to have tried everything and looked on every webpage so if anyone can give me a hand I'd be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for replying engineersmnky. Nexus is a Sonatype repository for storing artefacts. There's numerous versions of the gem but now its only finding half. Unfortunately, I can't be more specific about the gem itself. Please note that the version is there and should be accessible. Your bundle is locked to <gem> from rubygems repository <nexus repository> or installed locally, but that version can no longer be found in that source. That means the author of <gem> has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a version other than <gem> that hasn't been removed in orderto install.

Comment: They're not hosted by rubygems, they're hosted on Nexus. I was hoping there might be a few ideas as there are possibilities such as it not being present on the repository, a clash between the types of gem in the tree etc I've looked into this but other developers may have a few ideas I could try it. Don't worry if you can't help, its not problem.